# django перенос моей бд на heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

подскажите как можно перенести данные из локальной базы данных на мой проект на хероку, использую postgres

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

Comment: Делаешь бэкап тут/восстанавливаешь из бэкапа там https://habr.com/ru/post/485622/, с чего бы сам начал

Answer (score 0):

Для переноса записей из локальной базы можно воспользоваться `fixtures`

1. На локальной машине

   ```sh
   python3 manage.py dumpdata name_of_application > app.json
   ```
2. Скопировать файл в папку `fixtures`, которую создать в приложении на проде
3. И выгрузить в новую базу на проде

   ```sh
   python3 manage.py loaddata app.json
   ```

[Документация на английском здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures)